# SqlConnection and SqlCommand timing out

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, timeout

Just having some issues with a piece of code that is supposed to run over a set of SQL Server data. The idea is that it reads in resizes a jpeg file and writes it back out. It runs fine on a single row. However when run over a large set of data the subsequent rows the update command fails due to a timeout. Not on all rows but it does skip over the majority.

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace MesResizer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLconnString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con);
            GetRows(myConnection);
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        private static void GetRows(SqlConnection connection)
        {
            Boolean changed = false;

            using (connection)
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(16000) strIIImage, intIIID FROM InspectionItem;", connection);

                try
                {
                    Writeout("Setting up Database connection..");
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }

                Writeout("DONE");
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            int RowId = (int)reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("intIIID"));
                            Stream str;
                            changed = false;

                            try
                            {
                                str = reader.GetStream(reader.GetOrdinal("strIIImage"));

                                Image imgstr = Image.FromStream(str);
                                imgstr.Save("before.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                                if (str.Length > 0)
                                    changed = ScaleImage(Image.FromStream(str), ms);
                            }
                            catch (ArgumentException e)
                            {
                                Writeout("Stream does not have a valid image format or is Null... Unable to process image... " + RowId);
                                Writeout("Exception: " + e.Message);
                            }

                            if (changed)
                                WriteImage(ms, RowId);
                            else
                                Writeout("Image already resized: " + RowId);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Writeout("No rows found.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                reader.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void WriteImage(MemoryStream ms, int RowId)
        {
            var conf = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLconnString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection writecon = new SqlConnection(conf);

            writecon.Open();

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("after.jpg", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
            }

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE InspectionItem SET strIIImage = @Image WHERE intIIID = @Id", writecon))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, (int)ms.Length).Value = ms.ToArray();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RowId;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;

                try
                { //This is where it breaks. :)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    Writeout(e.Message + "Error occured on row: " + RowId);
                    return;
                }
            }

            Writeout("Succesfully Resized File: " + RowId);
            writecon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

There is a little bit of extra stuff going on here because I have been trying to verify the image stored is actually being resized and other things like the particular rows that were having the issue.

I have commented the code where the timeout is happening. :)

Any information or direction will be appreciated.

TIA.

*EDIT*
Ran over a number of image formats and a number of rows 5000+ on a test database and didn't have an issue at all. 
I can see that the data is that of a picture as I am writing each one out currently to disk but it doesn't seem to like to write back to the database all of the time. Very strange

*Edit*
Just incase anyone would like to know the resolution to this.

Ended up concluding that the SQLdatareader was locking rows on the database.

I am now selecting chunks of rows from the database moving them into a datatable closing the datareader and resizing and writing back when necessary.  I believe the key was to close the SqlDatareader and release any locks.

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Please paste only the relevant part

Comment: Sure ill update it.. didnt wanna leave anything irrelevant out.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

I also just noticed in your update call that you have `cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;`set.  This is a pretty short timeout, at only 5 seconds.  The default value for this is 30 seconds, you could easily need that much time to stream a file.

Initial post below:

There are a few things that could be happening here.  Since you are using a reader and going row-by-row you are keeping the initial connection open, it is possible that it will eventually time out as well.

As for your other connection issue, I wouldn't be surprised if you are getting a `timeout while getting a connection from pool` exception rather than a traditional timeout due to a maximum number of connections being reached.  As you are inside of a tight loop and constantly opening/closing connections.

I would also wrap the connection on your update inside of a using, due to your exception handling, the connection might not close, thus leading to an exhaustion of the pool resources so after the first timeouts you are setup for failure.

This isn't perfect, but changing to more like this could help.

```
    private static void WriteImage(MemoryStream ms, int RowId)
        {
            var conf = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLconnString"].ToString();
            //Added using
            using(SqlConnection writecon = new SqlConnection(conf))
{

            writecon.Open();

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("after.jpg", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
            }

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE InspectionItem SET strIIImage = @Image WHERE intIIID = @Id", writecon))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, (int)ms.Length).Value = ms.ToArray();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RowId;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 5;
                try
                { //This is where it breaks. :)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    Writeout(e.Message + "Error occured on row: " + RowId);
                    return;
                }
            }
            Writeout("Succesfully Resized File: " + RowId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does it get the connection from the pool when it executes the query or when i call open()? Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. Is the Exception message. :) Thankyou for your help.

Comment: The connection is established when you open.  If you are getting an actual timeout, you might want to look at the load on the server, to make sure that you are not maxing out on IO, or CPU, as that could delay, or if these images you are writing are very large.

Comment: @T-rent I just looked over your code again and edited my answer.  You are setting an explicit 5-second timeout.  With file write operations that is most likely too short.

Comment: Yeah i was experiencing the issue even with the default timeout. The application is being run locally and the images are quiet small. However i will have a look at this as well. Thankyou.